# How to go to a mediawiki extension page?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation

I installed mediawiki and `Special:Version` shows that `ConfirmEdit` extension is installed, but when I try to go to `index.php?title=Extension:ConfirmEdit` to configure it, I get nothing, how to go to that page to change its settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how extension configuration works. See [www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit) for instructions. Basically you have to edit the file LocalSettings.php in the root of your MediaWiki installation.